How to align y=0 point for dual y-axis in mpl finance?
I plotted the price data along with some indicators, e.g. MACD, KDJ using mpl finace. It works fine. The only thing is that in the MACD plot, the y axis of two curves (diff and dea) and the y axis of MACD histogram are not aligned. How to make the y=0 point of them coincide?
exp12 = data['Close'].ewm(span=12, adjust=False).mean()
exp26 = data['Close'].ewm(span=26, adjust=False).mean()

diff = exp12 - exp26
dea  = diff.ewm(span=9, adjust=False).mean()
macd = (diff - dea)*2

colors = ['g' if v >= 0 else 'r' for v in macd]

apds = [
        # moving average
        mpf.make_addplot(ma.tail(N2)['MA8'], color='red', width=0.7),
        mpf.make_addplot(ma.tail(N2)['MA20'], color='blue', width=0.7),
        mpf.make_addplot(ma.tail(N2)['MA60'], color='green', width=0.7),
        
        # MACD
        mpf.make_addplot(diff, panel=2,color='fuchsia',secondary_y=True,ylabel='MACD'),  
        mpf.make_addplot(dea,  panel=2,color='b',      secondary_y=True),
        mpf.make_addplot([0]*len(diff),panel=2,color='black', secondary_y=True, linestyle='dotted'),
        mpf.make_addplot(macd, panel=2,color=colors,   secondary_y=False,
                         type='bar',width=0.7,alpha=1),
        
        # KDJ
        mpf.make_addplot(kdj.tail(N2)['K'],panel=3,color='orangered',ylabel='KDJ'),
        mpf.make_addplot(kdj.tail(N2)['D'],panel=3,color='darkslateblue'),
        mpf.make_addplot(kdj.tail(N2)['J'],panel=3,color='limegreen'),
        mpf.make_addplot([70]*N2,panel=3,color='black', linestyle='dotted'),
        mpf.make_addplot([30]*N2,panel=3,color='black', linestyle='dotted'),
        mpf.make_addplot([50]*N2,panel=3,color='black', linestyle='dotted')
       ] 

mpf.plot(data_plot,
         type='candle',
         addplot=apds,
         figscale=1.1,
         figratio=(8,5),
         title='SA Price',
         style = 'yahoo',
         volume=True,
         volume_panel=1,
         panel_ratios=(6,2,3,3)
         )



Try setting secondary_y=False for your ZERO line:
mpf.make_addplot(diff, panel=2,color='fuchsia',secondary_y=True,ylabel='MACD'),  
mpf.make_addplot(dea,  panel=2,color='b'      ,secondary_y=True),

mpf.make_addplot([0]*len(diff),panel=2,color='black',secondary_y=False,linestyle='dotted'),
mpf.make_addplot(macd,panel=2,color=colors,secondary_y=False,type='bar',width=0.7,alpha=1),

That should work, but if it doesn't then try switching the secondary_y values:
mpf.make_addplot(diff, panel=2,color='fuchsia',secondary_y=False,ylabel='MACD'),  
mpf.make_addplot(dea,  panel=2,color='b'      ,secondary_y=False),

mpf.make_addplot([0]*len(diff),panel=2,color='black',secondary_y=True,linestyle='dotted'),
mpf.make_addplot(macd,panel=2,color=colors,secondary_y=True,type='bar',width=0.7,alpha=1),


At any rate, the zero-line and the histogram (what you call macd) should have the same secondary_y value.

The reason I plotted the dotted zero line is to show that the zero positions of the two y-axis, one for the histogram and the other for the diff and dea lines, do not match. The dotted line marks the zero position of y-axis for the diff and dea lines. Actually I don't need the dotted line. So the first solution is not what I want. What the second solution does is to move the dotted line to the zero posion of the histogram. It's not what I want as well.  It is a dual y-axis system. How to make the zero position of the two y-axis coincide?

@WenjieYu  It doesn't make sense for diff and dea to be have the same zero macd because they are on entirely different scales.    If you want, you can try to either (a) normalize them to the same scale (for example multiple macd by a factor that causes it to have approximately the same range (from min to max) as diff and dea, and then plot them all with secondary_y=False, or (b) continue using secondary_y=True and play with the ylim=(ymin,ymax) kwarg to try to get the two scales to line up with each other.

@WenjieYu  By the way, now that I think of it, simply setting secondary_y=False for all of the panel=2 make_addplot() calls will align the zero level for all plots on panel 2.  In addition to this, if you also scale or normalize the data, then the data with smaller magnitudes will be easier to see on that panel.
